# rosserial & sending str_msg

Tags: ros, arduino, rosserial, publisher

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Another really basic question but I cannot seem to figure it out:

I am trying to transmit data from a ROS node on an arduino. I figured that the best way to do this was through a str_msg. I have set the str_msg.data and I send that to my publisher which is set up to take in a str_msg. I am wondering if this is all that I need to do or if there are other fields that I need to populate before I even attempt to publish them?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/30048/rosserial-&-sending-str_msg/) by [BadRobot](https://answers.ros.org/users/1657/badrobot/) on ROS Answers with karma: 91 on 2012-03-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Check out the rosserial publisher tutorial, there's an example that does exactly that!

Here it is: http://www.ros.org/wiki/rosserial_arduino/Tutorials/Hello%20World

---

Originally posted by [Ernest](https://answers.ros.org/users/4002/ernest/) with karma: 341 on 2013-05-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1